# How to adjust the z-axis, if there is, for graphics in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, flashdevelop

I'm a beginner in FlashDevelop. I drew a simple circle. I also embedded a .jpg. Is there any way to place the circle I drew before the jpeg?

This is placed inside the init():

```
        [Embed (source = "images/Untitled.png")]
        var bg:Class;
        var bmp1:Bitmap = new bg;
        addChild(bmp1);
        var k:int, l:int;
            for (l = 0; l < 10; l++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                {
                    graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
                    graphics.drawCircle(k*50, l*50, 10);
                    graphics.endFill();
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by placing the circle before the jpeg?

Comment: I drew a circle using flash.Display.Graphics, I wanted it to be placed in front of the jpeg. Even if I placed the code block for embedding the image before drawing the circle, it is still placed in front.

Comment: You're probably drawing the circle on the Stage, while the JPEG is placed as a separate DisplayObject instance on top of the stage. Please edit your question and paste the code you're using into it. I'll be able to advise you better with that.

Comment: Yup, the problem was exactly what I had diagnosed. I've added the modified code as an answer below.

You should probably read up a bit on how the display list works in Flash. That should help you avoid such elementary problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Embed (source = "images/Untitled.png")]
var bg:Class;

var bmp1:Bitmap = new bg;
addChild(bmp1); // Add the bitmap first

var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(sprite1); // Add the sprite afterwards; it appears on top of the bitmap

var k:int, l:int;
for (l = 0; l < 10; l++)
{
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        sprite1.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
        sprite1.graphics.drawCircle(k*50, l*50, 10);
        sprite1.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attending to a small problem! Will do further readings!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at here is a topic called `The Display List`. Put very simply and very shortly, objects that are added to the `stage` (or other `containers`) will be displayed *in the order that they are added*, with the latest object going on top of the previous one.

**Pranav Negandhi**'s answer is correct in showing how to add your circle object infront/on-top/before your jpeg, but you should consider reading all or some of the following articles in order to fully understand the `display list` and what tools you have available to make objects appear just the way you want them on the screen.

[AS3 101: The Display List](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-the-display-list-basix--active-2255)

[Adobe's Display list programming in ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html)

[Republic Of Code's AS3: The Display List](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/)

You could also have a look through the reference for `displayobjectcontainer`, which contains most of the methods you'll be working with, such as `addChild()` or `addChildAt()`

[Display Object Container Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)

As always, feel free to ask questions here on `stackoverflow` if you need help!